# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\app'

Tags: npm, terminal, vite, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I ran on my WSL Ubuntu:

```bash
npm create vite@latest
```

And then I get this error:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\app'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1395:3)
    at Zr (file:///C:/Users/Karl/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/1415fee72ff6294b/node_modules/create-vite/dist/index.mjs:48:7741)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errno: -4048,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: 'C:\\Windows\\app'
}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't put your projects in `C:/Windows/`.

Comment: The Windows directory is read-only, and belongs to the OS. It's not yours to write to, and you're trying to do so, which is what's causing the error. My psychic debugging skills tell me that you just opened a command window and didn't change to the proper folder before you ran `npm`, and the command window was open in C:\Windows. As a programmer, you should learn how your operating system works before you start writing code that will run on it.